# Possible to avoid JSON-wrapper 'single entry' maps?

Tags: java, json, rest, gson, retrofit

A common pattern I see when writing stubs for REST interfaces with Retrofit2 is that often, the actual parameter needs to be wrapped with a map with a single entry (or, imo worse, a wrapper class consisting of a class with a single field).

Typical JSON payloads look like `{"idontcareaboutthis": { // Data I actually want...`. Is there a way to peel away this relatively useless outer shell ? It seems strange to me that all my REST methods have a return type of Map.

Comment: Use converters.
1. http://square.github.io/retrofit/#restadapter-configuration
2. `Retrofit.Builder.addConverterFactory(Converter.Factory factory)`
3. (If using Gson) Create a file similar to GsonConverterFactory.java adding your custom logic.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a map. You just can write your own JSON deserializer. Let's say, you have the following JSON where you don't need the root object single key:

```
{
    "idontcareaboutthis": {
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": 2
    }
}
```

Then a JSON deserializer might look like this:

```java
final class ResponseJsonDeserializer<T>
        implements JsonDeserializer<T> {

    private final Gson backingGson;

    private ResponseJsonDeserializer(final Gson backingGson) {
        this.backingGson = backingGson;
    }

    static <T> JsonDeserializer<T> getResponseJsonDeserializer(final Gson backingGson) {
        return new ResponseJsonDeserializer<>(backingGson);
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        final JsonObject root = json.getAsJsonObject();
        final Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries = root.entrySet();
        final int propertyCount = entries.size();
        if ( propertyCount != 1 ) {
            throw new JsonParseException("Expected a single property root object, but got an object with " + propertyCount + " properties");
        }
        final Entry<String, JsonElement> inner = entries.iterator().next();
        // Can't use context.deserialize here due to recursion
        return backingGson.fromJson(inner.getValue(), type);
    }

}
```

Note how the deserializer above extracts the root object entry and how it delegates the deserialization process to another Gson instance. Now you have to create a Gson instance that's aware of the `idontcareaboutthis` property.

```java
    private static final Gson registryBackingGson = new GsonBuilder()
            // whatever necessary here
            .create();

    private static final Gson registryGson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(FooBarResponse.class, getResponseJsonDeserializer(registryBackingGson))
            // add another response classes here like the above, but do not register other types - they must be registered in registryBackingGson
            .create();
```

`registryGson` requires either enumerating all the response classes or registering a specific type hierarchy. If the first case is not very convenient to you, and you can change the response classes source code, you could add a special marker interface in order to register the whole type hierarchy. Say, something like this:

```java
    private static final Gson registryBackingGson = new GsonBuilder()
            // whatever necessary here
            .create();

    private static final Gson registryGson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(IResponse.class, getResponseJsonDeserializer(registryBackingGson))
            // no need to add another "response" classes here - they just must implement the marker interface
            .create();
```

The data transfer object:

```java
final class FooBarResponse {

    // The `final` modifier is a reasonable habit for incoming DTO classes, but primitive constants are inlined by the compiler.
    // Suppressing the inlining can be done be a simple workaround to make javac think that it's not a real constant.
    // However, it's a matter of your code style, and this is just an example.
    private final int foo = constOf(0);
    private final int bar = constOf(0);

    int getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    int getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    // We're cheating...
    private static int constOf(final int i) {
        return i;
    }

}
```

And if you would prefer the marker interface and registering the whole type hierarchy

```java
interface IResponse {
}

final class FooBarResponse
        implements IResponse {
...
```

And how it works:

```
final FooBarResponse fooBar = registryGson.fromJson(JSON, FooBarResponse.class)
out.println(fooBar.getFoo()); // 1
out.println(fooBar.getBar()); // 2
```

Retrofit adapter:

```
final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        // ...
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(registryGson))
        .build();
```

Thus your Retrofit-base interface methods can return `FooBar`/etc class instances rather than maps.